# import pandas got error of "cannot import name 'doc'"?

Tags: python, pandas

I got the following error when import pandas. How to fix it?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import Appender, Substitution, doc
ImportError: cannot import name 'doc'
```

The command `conda list pandas` shows

```
/anaconda3/bin/conda list pandas
# packages in environment at /anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
geopandas                 0.9.0                     <pip>
pandas                    1.1.5                     <pip>
pandas                    0.22.0           py36hf484d3e_0
```

Comment: There's probably a problem with your pandas installation, how'd you install it? (I recommend anaconda)

Comment: i tried `conda uninstall panda` and `conda install panda`.

Comment: @ca9163d9, It should be `pandas` not `panda`.

Comment: @TonyMontana, typo, it was pandas. I updated the question. `conda list pandas` shows two pandas

Comment: May I know how did you install both the `pandas`? My advise would be to create he new Virtual environment and install pandas again